# Discord bot commands execute multiple times

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

It worked at first, but then somewhy it started to give the answers 4-5 times at once, any idea why?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def once_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} has joined the server.')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member} has left the server.')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong!')

client.run('my token here')
```

Comment: I also tried to reset the bot on my server but it didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750793/how-to-stop-running-discord-bot-process-python/60756179#60756179

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I indeed have the exact same problem, but I write it in Atom and I can't see anything to close already running instances

Comment: Sadly I do not know enough about Atom to help you with this problem. Your best bet is probably asking in the "atom" tag.

Comment: Yeah, I tried on Reddit as well, but probably I'm just gonna move to another compiler because I, along with others have no idea how to "fix" this. :C Thanks for your help tho :)

Comment: I reccomend running scripts in the commandline anyways. It doesn't take long to learn and also makes you more prepared for working in different envoirments, because running on the commandline always works and is easy to cancel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was that I couldn't **shut down** the **already running bots** in ***Atom***.

- If you add the code that I wrote down there (that only the owner can
  use) will shut down the already running bots (write /shutdown in
  discord server or whatever your prefix is).

However, you may need a PC restart after saving the bot with this code.

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def shutdown(ctx):
    await ctx.bot.logout()
```

- So every time if you want to edit your command, you write /shutdown
  and edit it, after that, you can start it again.

I hope this works for you and that I could help if you had the same problem.

Comment: Late thought: You could use the `atexit` library for teardown