# Discord Bot on python repeat both old and new code when making changes

Tags: python, discord.py

I just started a new project making Discord Bot using discord.py modules. I started simply by making the bot reply to a specific command. So my code look like this.

```
@bot.command()
async def id(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Your ID is {ctx.author}')
```

It works fine as expected, but when I make changes to the code, specifically I changed the message a bit, and when I head to the server and try out the command, the bot actually reply both the previous and the current message, which quite confuses me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750793/how-to-stop-running-discord-bot-process-python/60756179#60756179

Comment: Yes thank you, it worked