# How to stop if statements for my discord bot

Tags: python

so im trying to make a number guessing game discord bot. everything works fine until it reaches the end(where i want it to stop). i realized that even though the code ends, the bot is still  picking up things i say. is there any way i can stop this from happening?

(im only 15 years old and im a newbie at python so please be patient with me.)
heres my code :)

```
import keep_alive
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import sys


number = random.randint(1, 100)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("The bot is online")



@client.command()
async def numpuz(ctx):
  await ctx.send("Type a starting number")
 
  @client.command()
  async def num(ctx, chosennumber):
    if chosennumber > str(number):
      await ctx.send('number too high, pick a smaller one')
          
    if chosennumber < str(number):
      await ctx.send('number too small, pick a bigger one')
        
    if chosennumber == str(number):
      await ctx.send('YOU WON')
      
          
keep_alive.keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv("token"))
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with the discord API, but it looks like you're making a call to `keep_alive.keep_alive()`. By the name I'm guessing this just keeps the game running no matter what with an infinite loop, but I'm not sure since I'm not familiar with the packages. I would start there.

Comment: no,  i dont think this is the problem.  thats one of the things that allows me to  host this bot  24/7.  i  did remove it though and the problem  still persisted.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Unfortunately I am not familiar enough to provide additional help. Googling around it seems like you are supposed to kill the bot using `exit()` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750793/how-to-stop-running-discord-bot-process-python), but I think that kills the whole client and makes it a one-time run sort of thing which is not what you are going for. Hopefully someone else can give you a clearer picture. If this question isn't answered in a few days you should be able to put it up for bounty which will get more eyes on it.

Comment: yea, i tried exit() but unfortuneltely it only runs it once